# Sorting lists by lines/elements other than the 1st letter of the 1st line using HTML

Tags: html, list, sorting, element

I'm only now learning HTML and I came across how to sort a list on w3schools [ link -> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_list.asp ]

Using the code from that link, I replaced all the < li> elements (Oslo, Stockholm, Helsinki, etc...) with the following three:

Jessica< br>
London< br>
1975

Aaron< br>
Tokyo< br>
1962

Peter< br>
New York< br>
1958

Now, when I click 'sort', the list is of course sorted as expected, by the 1st letter of the 1st line, like this:

Aaron
Tokyo
1962

Jessica
London
1975

Peter
New York
1958

What I'd like, is to add 2 more sort buttons; one that sorts by the 2nd line, and another that sorts by the 3rd line. I made a diagram to better describe what I'm saying:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0CgV.png

[image]

Is that possible? Let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Modified Example,

use `sortList('2')` and `sortList('3')` for 2nd and 3rd row based sorting

- You can copy paste the following code at this url:
  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sort_list

Other URLs:

- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_list.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Sort a HTML List Alphabetically</title>
<body>

<p>Click the button to sort the list alphabetically:</p>
<button onclick="sortList('1')">Sort</button>

<div id="id01">
    <ul class="group">
        <li class="1">Aaron</li>
        <li class="2">Tokyo</li>
        <li class="3">2012</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="group">
        <li class="1">Jessica</li>
        <li class="2">London</li>
        <li class="3">2015</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="group">
        <li class="1">Peter</li>
        <li class="2">New York</li>
        <li class="3">2008</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
function sortList(sort_class_name) {
  /*
    sort_class_name - 1,2,3
  */
  var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch;
  list = document.getElementById("id01");
  switching = true;
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    // start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    b = list.getElementsByClassName(sort_class_name);
    console.log(b);
    // Loop through all list-items:
    for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
      // start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* check if the next item should
      switch place with the current item: */
      if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        /* if next item is alphabetically
        lower than current item, mark as a switch
        and break the loop: */
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark the switch as done: */
      b[i].parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1].parentNode, b[i].parentNode);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was just using some classes and sorting the elements' parent nodes. Hope it solves your problem!

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work fine. I'll examine it further and let you know, if I'm stuck anywhere. Also, sorry for the multiple dates (1975/1962/1958 and 2012/2015/2008). I accidentally mixed them. I corrected my original post, in order to avoid confusion in the future. Thanks :)